# How to read a value stored in an long int variable without using scanf in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program which ask a user for their 16 digit credit card number. I want to store the users input into a long int variable. How do I read the users input without using scanf?

Comment: Read it as a string and then convert that to the long int. To read there are functions like `fgets`. To convert `strtol`.

Comment: Can you read user input as a string? Also, I'd consider storing credit card number as a string, not as a long, anyway, because it's not really used as a number.

Comment: Are you sure, a `long int` is able to hold a 16 digit credit card number? What happens if your number starts with a `'0'`?

Comment: @kaylum Thanks this really helped!

Comment: @hyde my assignment was to store it as a long

Comment: @Gerhardh Yes, a long int worked, and if I get a number that starts with 0 I re-prompt the user using a do while loop

Comment: I actually edited my code below. It works fine, but I would like to know if its good code or if theres a better way of going about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
 char string[20];
 long int val;
 fgets(string, 19, stdin);
 val=atol(string); //atoi()/atol() for long int /atoll() any of these fns can be used
 printf("%s\n%d", string,val);

 return 0;
}
```

//Here you are converting string to long int later using atol
//Inputting string by fgets()

Comment: And if the user enters `QWERTY` instead of a number, `atol()` will still return a number.  Never use `atol()` or `atoi()` because they have absolutely no way of returning an error.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
long cn;
char buf[20];

do
{
    printf("card number please: ");
    fgets(buf, 19, stdin);
    cn = strtol(buf, NULL, 0);
}
while (cn < 1);

printf("%ld\n", cn);
}
```